# Rally-node NPM tool kit

Tags: rally

I can't able to access Rally data, Code was written one year back that time it was working fine now i am facing issue like "HTTP ERROR 401 -- Problem accessing   Full authentication is required to access this resource  Powered by Jetty:" any updation happened regarding rally-node npm toolkit.
I am using npm version 6.13 and
Node version 10.18

Help me in this

Thanks in Advance